# Regex filtering using JAVA

Tags: java, regex

How do I get a string which is between paranthesis using a regular expression in JAVA?
Eg: if  I have a string abc(de)gh
Then I want the "de" Substing.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what is the connection to PHP (your tags)?

Comment: I have tried a regex like /\(([^()]*)\)/i

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: `\((?<TEXT>[^()]+)\)` or `(?<=\()[^()]+(?=\))`

**Details**:

`\(` matches the character (

`(?<TEXT>)` Named Capture Group TEXT

`[^()]+` Match a single characteras not present in the list

`+` Matches between one and unlimited times

`\)` matches the character )

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NnMtsF/2)

Comment: Why a non-capture group? It is useless.

Comment: @Toto You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void test1() {

    String str = "abc(de)gh(il)jk";
    String regex = "\\((.*?)\\)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
    }

}
```

Comment: it doesn't work with: `abd(de)fgh(ij)kl`

Comment: Thank you.It worked

Comment: I changed regex. Try again.